# The pdf file after delete still showing on windows server 2008?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

My company has a server side using Windows Server 2008 Enterprise R2.

When a client is using Windows 7 Pro, copy the file onto the server. Then delete that file but the file still show, could not set name another file the same as the file after the delete command. Although after the deleted file still displayed but can not copy, move, open, delete ...

After a period of time the file will be lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in your open file's console on the windows server 2008 r2 to see if a lock is still there on the file please.

It happened to me in the past, an user was scanning a lot of documents and the scanner open a popup with the pdf. After she tried to delete the file that was stored onto the server  without success. The Windows 7 did not reported any error when she tried to erase too.

After investigating the issue I found that the user used to keep the file open on their desktop, and she didnt knew it because it was a multitabed pdf viewer .. As it maked the same symptom as you, as when she used to close the viewer hours later, the file was deleting correctly after..

The MMC look like that.

[image]

Comment: Thanks or support yagmoth555, I will check it and notice results. Thanks

Comment: Hello, I have examined the issue. It seems that the file being opened. I see it through the Open File Manager. If I close it in the Open File Manager, it will disappear. But on the client does not have any open the pdf file. I can not figure out the problem.

Comment: @SanNguyen What username you see on the console for the file ?

Comment: The username Guest is strange, check on the windows 7 if a unknown process keep the file open (like an antivirus), with process explorer, and select Find->Find Handle or DLL, and type the pdf short name

Comment: Thanks yagmoth555, I have finished repairing, Adobe Acrobat was close but it not close :(.